# How to load a specific html file in the BrowserWindow

Tags: electron

I am creating an app in Electron. I am still new to the framework however I 
did some reading around how to communicate between the main and renderer 
processes using ipcMain and ipcRenderer. I have a simple html page with a 
login form that gets load when the app is ready and in the renderer process 
I listen 
to the click event of the submit button on the form(For testing purposes I 
have hard coded the username and password) and I run a simple check to see 
if the password and username matches the one I have hard coded. The aim is 
to then load a specific html file in the browser window based on the result 
of the check. My render.js looks like this:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function (event){
event.preventDefault();
const username = 'Belinda';
const password = 'admin';

const inputUsername = document.querySelector('#username').value;
const  inputPassword = document.querySelector('#password').value;

if(inputUsername != username || inputPassword != password){
    ipc.send('errortest', function (){
        alert('Error')

    });
}else{
    ipc.send('successtest', function (){ 
        alert('Success')
    });
 };
});
```

In main.js I listen to the events like this:

```
ipc.on('successtest', function (){
    mainWindow.loadFile('admin.html');
});
ipc.on('errortest', function(){
   console.log('error');
   mainWindow.loadFile('error.html');
});
```

My index.html page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/@fortawesome/fontawesome- 
  free/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/main.css">

  <!-- <link rel="import" href="./admin.html"> -->
 <link rel="import" href="./admin.html">
 <link rel="import" href="./error.html">
 </head>
 <body id="body">
 <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
    <div class="text-center mb-4">
      <img class="mb-4" src="./assets/icons/logo4.jpg" alt="" width="80" 
     height="40">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" value="" autofocus class="form-control form- 
    control-sm" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" autofocus value="" class="form-control form- 
    control-sm success" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-sm" id="btn" 
    type="submit">Log in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">&copy; Save Money 
   Solutions 2018-19</p>
 </form>

 <script>
 require('./renderer');
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Running the app works only for the 'errortest' event. Any advice on how I 
get around this. Or any Ideas on how to do basic login and redirect paths 
in electron. I did try some research but I haven't come across anything 
useful. Thank you

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Comment: Thanks for the html update. I cloned the "electron quickstart" repository, and changed index.html as follows: <input type="text" id="username"><br>
    <input type="password" id="password"><br>
    <button id="btn">Click</button> and used your js files. This works for me (I go to admin page). Some tips: remember you can use "normal" Chrome dev tools in Electron, which can help you debug. Also try "alerting" the values from your selector query to confirm they are what you expect.

Comment: Perhaps try similarly get it working on the electron quickstart repo here: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start in a minimal way, then transfer knowledge into your actual app

Comment: I made a small example from the quick start here: https://github.com/grahammcallister/electron-quick-start-logindemo

Comment: Your broader question about doing login: it depends on the needs of your application and users :-) For example maybe you need to use the Windows credentials of the signed in user, or maybe you're signing in to a back end API. Electron doesn't recommend or constrain you to a specific way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamMC however, I still have the same problem. I also cloned the demo login repository you created and yes its taking me to the Login and error page but other code blocks in the renderer.js file is not being executed. For instance the alert() is not working.

Comment: Strange. The demo solution works for me. I'd recommend using Dev Tools to debug and make sure the values match up. You can also set a break point on main using an IDE like Visual Studio Code to catch the main rpc functions and confirm what values are coming

Comment: Note that the alerts won't run as they're being sent as parameters to the IPC function - they would only be seen on the main as parameters, they're never executed. Does that make sense now?

Comment: ipc.send('successtest', function (){ 
        alert('Success')
    }); // you're sending the function with the alert as a parameter to the send method, it will never run in renderer

Comment: Rather do this: if(inputUsername != username || inputPassword != password){
    alert('Error');
    ipc.send('errortest');    }

Comment: @GrahamMc, apparently the problem was with my If() statements. They both needed to be returned (success as true and error as false). Its now working as intended. Thanks

Comment: Glad you came right :-) enjoy Electron

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is how you're getting the value of the username and password inputs.

Since both of your inputs has ids I think you should be getting their value like this:

```
const inputUsername = document.getElementById('username').value;
const inputPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Using the `getElementById` function.